# Placing listview into a stack panel breaks vertical scrolling

Tags: .net, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

In my layout, I have two sections that would have a variable height I wanted to be able flow one section after another so I created a stackpanel. Inside the stack panel is another stack panel and a listview. For some reason, when the listview is inside of this outer stackpanel, I cannot scroll vertically. There is clearly more items to be seen -- I can pull the items list up (that rubbbery effect you get when you pull an element beyond it's content) and see plenty more items, but I cannot scroll through them. When I move the listview out of the stack panel, it scrolls perfectly but this breaks the intended layout. Any Ideas? Here is the xaml for this section:

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <StackPanel DataContext="{Binding SelectedLink}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Author}" Foreground="Blue" FontSize="20"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding SelfText}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="0, 20, 0, 0" />
        </StackPanel>
        <ListView x:Name="CommentsListView" ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedLinkComments}" IsItemClickEnabled="True" IsSwipeEnabled="False" IsHoldingEnabled="True" Holding="CommentsListView_OnHolding">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border BorderBrush="Gray" Padding="2" Margin="2">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Author}" Foreground="Green"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Body}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: what are the outer grid row height definitions?

Comment: like one might expect. 2 Rows, (Auto, *) and 2 Columns (Auto, *)

Comment: Since the StackPanel will grow to fit the entire list, the solution is to remove the outer StackPanel and add rows to the inner Grid (auto, *) and place the inner StackPanel in Row 0 and the ListView in Row 1.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0">
        <!-- your textblocks -->
    </StackPanel>
    <ListView Grid.Row="1" />
</Grid>
```

That will let it scroll just fine.

Best of luck!

Comment: LOL - great, you made an answer out of my comment above.